# How can I avoid SSH's host verification for known hosts?

Tags: linux, ssh

I get the following prompt everytime I try to connect a server using SSH. I type "yes", but is there a way to aovid this?

```
The authenticity of host '111.222.333.444 (111.222.333.444)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is f3:cf:58:ae:71:0b:c8:04:6f:34:a3:b2:e4:1e:0c:8b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: /dev/null exists for those who think they are immune to man in the middle attacks :)

Comment: Worst part: Type `y` to save some time, and it complains: `Please type 'yes' or 'no':` [_(hmph)_](https://media.giphy.com/media/Q4ScVMm5oBP44/giphy.gif)

Comment: similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh/167753#167753

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Use the `-o` option,

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" user@host
```

Comment: You may want to use an alternate identity file with the flag '-i'

Comment: What use would using an alternate identity file be? I mean, if you're connecting to a compromised host, what difference does it make how you authenticate - it's not like the compromised host can steal your key too.

Comment: Perfectly valid answer.  Just please note that this is insecure, and it opens you up to "man-in-the-middle" attacks.

Comment: On my computer a related man page (`man 5 ssh_config`) says that there are more alternatives to `no`, including `accept-new`, where ssh "will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files, but will not permit connections to hosts with changed host keys." This seems like it would still solve this problem in many cases while being more secure. (There is also `yes`, which skips the prompt and rejects unknown and changed hosts. Also `off` is the same as `no` and `ask` is the default, which prompts.)

Comment: According to [the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html), `StrictHostKeyChecking` will "automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files" when set to `no` or `off`, which is worth noting. See [JimFred's answer](https://superuser.com/a/628801/1732018) if you just want to connect once without adding anything to the known hosts (may be useful in some cases).

Answer (score 155):

Add the following lines to the beginning of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`...

```
Host 192.168.0.*
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Options:

- The Host subnet can be `*` to allow unrestricted access to all IPs.
- Edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for global configuration or `~/.ssh/config` for user-specific configuration.

See http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-disable-ssh-host-key-checking.html

Comment: Pity I can only upvote you once.  Setting KnownHosts to /dev/null is genius.

Comment: Your the smartest one.

Comment: Ha! Tell my wife.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: From experience when mixing space-separated and `=` separated options in an `.ssh/config` SSH sometimes seems to choke on the latter. Better to stay consistent.

Answer (score 29):

You should only get this the first time you connect to a new host. After you respond `yes` the host gets stored in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and you won't get prompted the next time you connect.

Note that if `~/.ssh/known_hosts` can not be written for any reason (e.g. permissions problem) then you will get prompted every time you connect.

Comment: The question is is there anyway to avoid the prompt?

Comment: I tried adding "CheckHostIP no" to /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.
But it does not seem to be working

Comment: sudo chown -R user:user .ssh ; sudo chmod 700 .ssh;  sudo chmod -R 600 .ssh/ ;  ssh-keygen -R $hostname and reconnect  that  should take ALL problems out and ONLY ever re-prompt if a ssk_Hostkey is  mucked with | changed or you are  victim to a MITM.

Comment: it says "everytime" so this answer is super appropriate

Comment: No, it's a terrible answer, because obviously IT KEEPS HAPPENING to the guy, or he wouldn't have asked the question.  And to me, too, because I have an IT department that decides they need to "clean out" the known_hosts files on a regular basis.

Answer (score 11):

The best way (because it does not sacrifice security) is to connect once to all computers from one client (you'll be prompted every time, always answer yes). As pointed out in the other answer, the keys will then be stored in ~/.ssh/known_hosts. Then copy this file to every client computer you might later want to connect from (possibly for each user account you use). Then all these accounts will "know" the computers, hence no prompt.

The advantage over just disabling the prompt is that SSH can actually check if there is a MITM attack.

Comment: Although, if you often ssh via forward connections, you will want to add this to /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

Host 127.0.0.1
 NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes

Comment: Meanwhile there is a tool named `ssh-keyscan` to achieve this. You can, btw, also store the keys in `/etc/ssh` with restrictive permissions to hold the values for those servers that you _know_ won't change and then populate these via a tool like Ansible, Chef or Puppet ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable the confirmation, rather than the authentication, you can use the option: "-o CheckHostIP=no"

```
ssh -i sergeys_rsa_key.pem -o CheckHostIP=no brin@8.8.8.8
```

Comment: The OP has already got the same answer and accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue where despite using the above mentioned verified solution, my ssh was not working and it was because the known_hosts file was missing from ~/.ssh/ directory and the File System was read only. SO during run time also I was unable to create the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.

If you face the similar issue then see if you can write the known_hosts file in the /tmp location. This is mostly write enabled even in a read-only file system.

Later in the ssh command you can specify the ssh to read the known_hosts file from /tmp location.

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user_name@destination_server_ip
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because your ssh key server changed, since server ip or domain is the same but ssh key mismatch.

You must remove the stored key in `/home/$user/.ssh/known_hosts` to avoid this message.

I fixed it removing all keys in that file, so new token is created for this domain name.

Comment: Key *changed* produces a much uglier message with a box of atsigns and `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!` 
and `IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!` in all-caps. The message in the question occurs 
only if there is *not* already an entry in `known_hosts`.

Answer (score -2):

Check the permissions on your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Mine were incorrect when I got this problem.  I fixed it with:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```