# SSH: known host with dynamic address

Tags: ssh, public-key, known-hosts

I need to connect to a host with a dynamic IP address.

Every time its IP changes, SSH prompts me the fingerprint validation thing:

```
The authenticity of host '...' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

---

Would it be possible to pass SSH the host public key, so that:

1. SSH validates the host's authenticity automatically
2. The host key is not stored in the known_hosts file

---

This question differs from [How can I avoid SSH's host verification for known hosts?](https://superuser.com/questions/125324/how-can-i-avoid-sshs-host-verification-for-known-hosts) since that other questions aims to suppress SSH validation, while I do **not** want to suppress it: I **do** want to have the host authenticated, just using the host's public key (which I know, and have it stored in a file) rather than SSH `known_hosts` file.

To me the other question seems to be about connecting to a different server every time, rather than connecting to a single well-known server with a dynamic IP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution (ie. closest to what I want) I could find is to use the option `HostKeyAlias`: it will use an hostname I specify to access `known_hosts` (rather than the IP I'm connecting to).

I will need to add the host's public key to `known_hosts` using a given hostname (eg: `myhost`) and then connect to it using:

```
ssh -o 'HostKeyAlias myhost' ...
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but: if this best answers your question, please accept it.

Comment: Note for others: you can add the `HostKeyAlias` config value to your `~/.ssh/config` file or even to the global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file.

Answer (score 9):

The `known_hosts` file is not just the key, it also contains the hostname you use to connect, and if possible the IP that corresponds. Which is why you see the error, it is comparing the triplet it gets from the server with what you stored in the known_hosts file.

So, if the IP keeps changing, you could disable `CheckHostIP` and that means it will just check the hostname and host key. If those remain unaltered, you should have less complaints, but you will be at risk if someone hijacks your DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test it asap! Why would it be at rist anyway? If I know a host's SSH public key, that should be enough to be totally safe in any case (unless somebody manages to steal that host's private key), shouldn't it?

Comment: And still I don't really like it if I have to be honest. Using that flag SSH will still access `known_hosts`. Why? Cannot I say "ssh connect to X whose public key is Y"? Why not? Wouldn't that be 100% sure.

Comment: The idea is that the host key is part of a larger whole, and that alone is not enough guarantee to be sure the server you are connecting to is still the one you connected to earlier. You need to be sure the IP, and DNS entries match as well.. remember, this is a network based shell, so the network needs to be checked as well.